# Decoding QR Code in Java using ZXing issue

Tags: java, pdf, png, qr-code, zxing

I'm running into an issue using ZXing in Java. Here's the deal, I have a PDF that includes a QR Code. I use Imagemagick to convert the PDF to a 300dpi, monochrome PNG file, which I feed to my decode class:

```
Result result = null;
BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap;

    try{

        binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(ImageIO.read(
                new FileInputStream(filename)))));
        result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap);
        System.out.println("QR Code: "+result.getText());

        return result.getText();

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
```

The decode class is unable to find a QR code in the image, even if I crop out everything BUT the QR code in the PNG file. I have 20 different PDFs like this and none of them work. The crazy part is that the Android app Barcode Scanner has no issue reading the QR code, whether it's in the PDF or in the PNG file. Isn't the Barcode Scanner app based on the ZXing code? I have used other QR codes with the Java class and they are decoding, so I know the function does work. Any suggestions are most appreciated, thanks.

-SL

Comment: Why are you not posting the actual image?

Comment: Java is a word and not an acronym

Comment: Sean: it contains sensitive information.

Comment: Steve: thanks for the informative response...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried PURE_BARCODE as well TRY_HARDER, still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm using tcpdf to create the QR code (type H) and putting it on a cover sheet. The cover sheet is then faxed back and delivered via email as a PDF. Like I said, the barcode scanner android app has no problem reading the QR code. The Zxing web decoder, or the class I've written can't read them.

Comment: Something is probably going wrong in the image conversion process upstream. Try any other QR code image to test that. If still no go, create an example that fails without containing sensitive info and post it.

Comment: here is a sample image that is not readable by my class, or with the ZXing web decoder, but it IS readable using the barcode scanner Android app: http://i.imgur.com/Z5kJRXcs.jpg

Comment: it might be too tiny, I don't really know why but we experimented the same effect. Try to enlarge your image, even if it blurs.